# python calculate time for ML learning process

Tags: python, time

Im using scikit-learn to train some models in Jupyter Lab (IPython) and its something I let it run on my Windows 10 laptop that can take a few hours.

Would anyone have any tips for calculating the time to train? In IPython I just do a run all cells and use this code in the beginning & end cell. For example-

```
import time

print('Lets GO!')
start = time.ctime()
```

Come back a few hours later, (ML training code running)

```
end = time.ctime()

print('all done!')
print('started', start)
print('finished',end)
```

I can only glance at the time difference but is it possible to give me a elapsed hours & minutes between start and end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `datetime.datetime.now()`; you can subtract two `datetime` instances and get a `timedelta` describing the difference:

```
>>> import time, datetime
>>> start = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> time.sleep(10)
>>> end = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> diff = (end - start)
datetime.timedelta(seconds=10, microseconds=885206)
>>>
```

To format a hours/minutes/seconds out of that,

```
>>> diff_seconds = int(diff.total_seconds())
>>> minute_seconds, seconds = divmod(diff_seconds, 60)
>>> hours, minutes = divmod(minute_seconds, 60)
>>> hms = f"{hours}h {minutes}m {seconds}s"
'0h 0m 10s'
```